# How to serialize an Enum with a custom string name using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net-core, serialization, system.text.json

I have some problems when customizing Enum values as a string.

```
public sealed class SerializationTest
{
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public SerializationType Type { get; set; }
}


public enum SerializationType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "system_serialization")]
    System = 1,

    [EnumMember(Value = "custom_serialization")]
    Custom = 2
}
```

Look at the example above. I have an Enum with two values: System and Custom. But I want to change the name when the serialization occurs:

- System -> system_serialization
- Custom -> custom_serialization

I tried using a specific `JsonSerializerOptions` with a `JsonStringEnumConverter` but it doesn't work.

When I try to serialize the `SerializationTest` object the process doesn't work. I'm trying something like this:

```
.
.
.
var myObject = new SerializationTest
{
    Type = SerializationType.System
};

var content = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myObject);
.
.
.
```

I'm getting the following results:
{"type":"System"}
But I need:
{"type":"system_serialization"}

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonStringEnumMemberConverter` from [`Macross.Json.Extensions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Macross.Json.Extensions/) which scans for `EnumMemberAttribute`:

```cs
public sealed class SerializationTest
{
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumMemberConverter))] 
    public SerializationType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively you can write your own [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0) (or better [converter factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#sample-factory-pattern-converter)) which will read the attributes and read/write them.

Comment: Supposing I use a custom converter, how would I get the custom name provided to the enum?

Comment: @LucasRafaell 1) English please 2) by getting the attribute via reflection (ideally cache it)